Strong law of large numbers: Problem with formulation of almost sure convergence
I have a source, where the law of large numbers is stated as follows:
Let $(X_i, i \geq 1)$ be a sequence of independent random variables following the same distribution as a random variable $X$. We assume, that $E(|X|) < + \infty$. Then, for almost every $\omega$ (this means that there exists $N \subset \Omega$ with $P(N) = 0$ and that if $\omega \not \in N$):
$E(X) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} (X_1(\omega) + ... + X_n(\omega) )$
I have to admit, that I don't understand this formulation. If we consider for example a dice with $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and $X = X_i: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \omega \mapsto \omega$, i.e. for example $X_i(3) = 3$. Then $E(x) = 3.5$, but, for e.g. $\omega = 1$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} (X_1(1) + ... + X_n(1) ) = 1$.
What am I mistaking?

Since all of the $X_i$ are identical and non-constant, they are not independent.

Your sample space has 6 outcomes, but there are $6^n$ outcomes when one throws $n$ dice...

Your sample space should be ample enough to host any sequence of indefinite observations of die rolls, and this means that you need an infinite (and in fact, uncountable) sample space to begin with.

The comments of math-jl and zhoraster answer your question (I have upvoted them). You may not be able to give feedback unless someone formally provides an answer, so I am doing that.

If you want to consider an infinite sequence of independent and fair dice rolls, then you need a sample space $\Omega$ that is uncountably infinite. You could use
$$ \Omega = \{(d_1, d_2, d_3, ...) : d_i \in \{1, ..., 6\} \quad \forall i \in\mathbb{N}\}$$
so each $\omega \in \Omega$ has the form
$\omega = (d_1, d_2, d_3, ...)$.
Then you can define random variables
$$ X_i(\omega) = X_i(d_1, d_2, d_3, ...) = d_i \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$$
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all subsets of $\Omega$ that are events. Assume we have a probability measure $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow[0,1]$ under which the random variables are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) with
$$P[X_i=d] = 1/6 \quad \forall d \in \{1, ..., 6\}, i \in \mathbb{N}$$
and so
$$E[X_i]=\frac{1}{6}(1+2+3+4+5+6) = 3.5 \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$$
Define $\omega_1 \in \Omega$ as the outcome where all dice rolls are 1; define $\omega_2\in\Omega$ as the outcome where dice rolls alternate between 2 and 3:
\begin{align*}
&\omega_1 = (1, 1, 1 ,1, 1 ,...)\\
&\omega_2 = (2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, ...)
\end{align*}
It is clear that
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i(\omega_1) = 1\\
&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i(\omega_2) = 2.5\\
\end{align}
Therefore, $\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}\subseteq N$, where $N$ is the subset of all outcomes in $\Omega$ for which $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i(\omega)$ does not converge to 3.5. The set $N$ contains more than just the two outcomes $\omega_1, \omega_2$. In fact, $N$ contains uncountably infinitely many outcomes.  However, the law of large numbers says that
$$P[N]=0$$
It means that, even though there are infinitely many outcomes under which the desired limit does not converge to 3.5, the probability that the randomly selected outcome produces a limit that does not converge to 3.5 is zero. With probability 1 we will have an outcome in $N^c$. So there are also infinitely many outcomes where the desired limit does converge to 3.5, and the collective probability of those outcomes dominates.
It is easy to see that $P[\{\omega_1\}]=0$ because
$$P[\cap_{i=1}^{n}\{X_i=1\}]= (1/6)^n$$
$$P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{X_i=1\}]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1/6)^n=0$$
Similarly, it is easy to see that $P[\{\omega_2\}]=0$. In fact, the probability of any particular outcome is zero. However, it is not obvious that if we collect all uncountably infinite number of outcomes $\omega$ for which the desired limit fails into a set $N$, that $P[N]=0$. That is why the law of large numbers is so remarkable.

Exercises:

Give two new examples of outcomes $\omega_3$ and $\omega_4$ that are in $N$.

Give two examples of outcomes $\omega_5$ and $\omega_6$ that are in $N^c$.

Explain why $N$ has infinitely many outcomes.


